# DOM selectors vs Render functions

Tags: javascript

I've made a JSPerf test: https://jsperf.com/dom-selector-vs-re-render.
In this example, I have an `<ul>` list where I remove a class from one of its `<li>` and add it to another. Also, I change the content of each `<li>`.

The goal was to compare the performance of making this between:

1. Changing each DOM element;
2. Re-rendering every `<li>` and than inject it in the DOM.

Surprisingly, I found out that the first option is more than 10 times faster than the second one. Nevertheless, I thought that the trend (like reactive frameworks does) was to re-render the DOM.

Did I make anything wrong in the test? Should I re-render the DOM only in certain cases? Can you explain this result?

Comment: I am just learning React and reading through the documentation I found that react only render children components of a given DOM element so I think this is what you are seeing in your test.
https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom.html <- read the render section for more information

Comment: Reactive frameworks don't re-render the DOM, they re-render a virtual DOM that then is used to update the actual DOM via diffing techniques.

Comment: It should be noted that the "slow" version benchmarks at being able to perform over 10,000 DOM replacements per second (on my laptop), which seems pretty good.

Comment: So, if I understand, the difference between my test and Reactive frameworks is that it only renders the needed parts of the DOM. Right?

Comment: @Pointy, you're right. Anyway, I was curious.

Answer (score 0):

Changing each DOM element is faster, but re-rendering every `<li>` and than inject it in the DOM is still fast and can be better for development.